# enable an end user to type in - pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to Write a PLSQL program to enable an end user to type in the customer_ID. Display the list of unique product_IDs that customer purchased from the sales table.

```
BEGIN
  FOR p IN (SELECT unique product_id FROM sales)
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line( 'Customer ID: ' || p.product_id );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I have solved the second part of displaying the unique values as follows but not sure how to enable an end user to type in the customer_id?? help

Comment: PL/SQL is not an interactive language.  It has no facility to prompt a user for a value.  You can write a SQL*Plus script that will prompt the user for a value and submit a PL/SQL block to the database with the user's response substituted in.  Or you can write a stored procedure that accepts a parameter that any application can call passing in a value.  The latter is much more conventional (though in reality you'd never have a procedure that simply writes to `dbms_output`) but that puts the onus of prompting the user on the calling application.

Comment: You can use bind variables to capture info from user and substitute the variable in SQL.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site where you can ask questions and get answers about problems you're having with software you've written, but it is not a "do my homework for me" site. When you ask a question you should include the code you've written and the specific errors you're getting or the results your program produces and an explanation of the results you expected. Without that there's really not much we can do to help you. Please edit your question to show what you've done and tell us what problems the code has. Again, welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ampersend (&) sign as a placeholder in your PL/SQL block. Like this :

```
BEGIN
  FOR p IN (SELECT unique product_id FROM sales WHERE customer_id = &1)
  LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line( 'Customer ID: ' || p.product_id );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: what if I have several rows of customers_id to be inserted by end user..I think we'll have to add a nested for clause after Where .. what do you think the statment would be?

Comment: @Jaad - PL/SQL isn't an interactive language.  You can't prompt for values in a loop.  This is a SQL*Plus script where the SQL*Plus client prompts the user for a substitution value before submitting the modified PL/SQL block to the database.  If you know exactly how many `customer_id` values you want to prompt for, you could have an `IN` clause.  But that seems exceedingly unlikely.  More likely, you would want a more general solution.

Comment: when I get promoted to enter a value, lets say I enter '1'.. the output would be like the following , I dont really understand why the first 2,3 were added? on what calculated basis this was done?

Enter value for 1: 1
old   5:   FOR p IN (SELECT product_id FROM sales WHERE customer_id = &1)
new   5:   FOR p IN (SELECT product_id FROM sales WHERE customer_id = 1)
Customer ID: 2
Customer ID: 3
Customer ID: 7
Customer ID: 4
Customer ID: 3
Customer ID: 2
Customer ID: 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.